# What is a short form for Institute of Linguistics?

Tags: abbreviations

What is a short form for "Institute of Linguistics"? Should it be IL or IOL?

Comment: Ask the organisation for the acronym or short-form. Perhaps, visit their web site.

Answer (score 1):

**Ask them** what abbreviation they prefer, i.e., which one they use themselves (if they use one).  There is no real rule for this kind of thing in English.  Try to find out from the source what they prefer to be called (and respect that, if you don't have a reason not to).

Answer (score 0):

If you were to go by this University of Minnesota [page](http://linguistics.umn.edu/), it's *IoL*.

> **Institute of Linguistics**
>
> The Institute of Linguistics (IoL) is the academic home of faculty and
>   students in linguistics, the scientific study of human language, and
>   its subfields.